# Why is this 'except:' line throwing a syntax error?

Tags: python

I'm doing database things and I have this code

```
for res_posts in list_of_response_ids:
    temp_str = res_posts[0] # first element of res_posts tuple is string
    temp_str += ":" + output
    try:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO POST (res_post_id) where post_id = '%s';" % (temp_str, res_posts(1))
    except:
        print "life sucks"
db.close()
```

A syntax error is thrown like so:

```
$ python post.cgi
  File "post.cgi", line 85
    except:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is this happening? I can post more code if you need more information.

Thank you!

Comment: Standard procedure for syntax errors you don't get: go back a line, check your parentheses.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll keep that in mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing a parenthesis

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO POST (res_post_id) where post_id = '%s';" % (temp_str, res_posts(1)))###<---Here
```

Comment: Haha, I looked at that line but didn't notice my mistake. Thank you very much!